# How to point a domain in DigitalOcean to Route 53?

Tags: dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, digital-ocean, amazon-route53

[image: Route 53 settings]

Above is my Route 53 settings, the project is hosted in Elastic Beanstalk. But the domain I put it on [DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/abb622813f68) *(see the screenshot below)*

[image: DigitalOcean networking]

Which part I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the A record on Digital Ocean. (The A record in Route53 will be used)

In Route53, you need to create a new record in your hosted zone. Enter your domain name in the Name field, Select A-IPv4, Select yes a for alias target, click in the box and then chose your EBS environment. Then save Record Set.

Full documentation from AWS can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Comment: Are you able to access your site using the Elastic Beanstalk URL for your environment?

Comment: I use another domain for it, i change the nameserver directly from namecheap.com, instead of point to digitalocean. Without DO middleman then it works

Comment: Glad that worked out for you. Hopefully my answer pointed you in the right direction. :)